# Java Socket: Read/receive the same instance multiple times after change values: ObjectInputStream.readObject()

Tags: java, sockets, object, serialization

I'm developing a simple multiplayer game with a server. The concept is to send the object "game" after every turn of a player to all clients. It contains all information the clients need. It works well the first time. After the second time the values of the object in the client aren't changed. It is confirmed that the values are changed on the server and I also set the object to null on the client side before reading. I am not experienced in Java. Is it possible that "Java" thinks because it is the same instance it will not read the new values and just reactivate the old values (maybe from a cache)?

Client Code

```
this.game = null;
this.game = (Game) ois.readObject();
```

Server Code

```
aCPS.get(i).oos.writeObject(game);
```

Game

```
public class Game implements Serializable {...}
```

Please tell me if you need more code. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write the same object to an `ObjectOutputStream` without resetting, you will get the same object. This is how Java Serialisation handles arbitrary object graphs.

To fix, best off using a fresh `ObjectOutputStream`. You can call `reset` on it. Or use immutable objects or use something else for serialisation.

Comment: @EJB A bit pointless and confusing. All the contained objects will still be shared.

Comment: It is neither pointless nor confusing, and it should be mentioned for completeness. If the OP doesn't care about the contained objects, or there aren't any, it is just as good a solution as the others you mentioned.

Comment: @EJP It's a complete misfeature. It does not achieve what it was intended to do.

Comment: I don't see that. It does exactly what it is documented to do. "Note that the rules described above only apply to the base-level object written with writeUnshared, and not to any transitively referenced sub-objects in the object graph to be serialized."

Comment: Thank you. The new server code for every time the object is sent is:
    aCPS.get(i).oos.reset();
    aCPS.get(i).oos.writeObject(obj);